# How can I force browser to refresh the cache with php?

Tags: php, html, css, caching, filemtime

I am a beginner web "developer". I'm making the site of our dog kennel.
I've been facing the cache problem for days. I found out PHP filemtime could do the job, I just want to ask, if I put the PHP code like this, would it work?
If not, could you help me please, how to do this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../styles/basic.css?v=<?php filemtime('../../../styles/basic.css') ?>"/>
```

Comment: Yeah this will probably work. It's a very basic way of versioning assets, but it will do the trick I think.